# Google Map not showing up in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

1) It's **showing empty map with grey color** only with +(zoom in) and -(zoom out) buttons.

2) I **extracted the SHA1 key** from the **debug.keystore** and **generated the MAP API V2 key** in the 
console.

3) I **pasted** that key **in the manifest** file.

4) GOOGLE **MAP API V2 switched ON**

and i use my Nexus 7 for debugging(USB Debugging)

- LogCat Message :

> **Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network
>   errors).**

Please help if i went somewhere wrong in these files.

**AndoidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="metro.tailors"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <permission android:name="metro.tailors.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="metro.tailors.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name="metro.tailors.MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="metro.tailors.FactorsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_factors" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="metro.tailors.LadiesCategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ladies_category" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="metro.tailors.GentsCategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gents_category" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="metro.tailors.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="AIzaSyA2pMJiaPfwlz2yKaRNMZHykQkY_******"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**This the XML File of the MapActivity**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
        package metro.tailors;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;

        public class MapActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            }

        }
```

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="10" you should use support fragment in this case. Check the key again. See if you have enabled maps in the api console.

Comment: Also make sure you have properly referred to google play services library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
4) GOOGLE MAP API V2 switched ON
```

You should turn on `Google Maps for Android`:

[image]

`Fragment` support start only from `API > 11`, So either change your `manifest` file to that or add android-support Library and use the `SupportMapFragment` object along side with `FragmentActivity`.

To download support library check the below link.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Downloading

The doc states **Use MapFragment class only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment.**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Raghunandan, I wasn't sure about the package level that should be used  : )

Comment: You are welcome. glad i could spot and help you with the answer.

Comment: Thanks @EmilAdz
I turned on the Google Maps API V2 instead of the Android Maps API V2 and also changed the manifest file.
Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

`2) I extracted the SHA1 key from the debug.keystore and generated the MAP API V2 key in the console.`

Not only do you have to do this, you also have to add your app to the list of allowed apps in the Google API Console, with your debug key and package name, as well as with your production keystore key and package name